# socket.recv() is not firing on sending side

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a very simple rdt 2.2 socket program that transfers an image file dictated as "Cat.bmp" from client to server. Once the client reads the first line of data from the bmp file, it sends it to the server, and then the server will continue to repeat reading this same line in an infinite loop. I have no idea why this won't allow the client to send new data. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be very appreciated.

**Client.py**

```
import binascii
import struct
import sys
import hashlib
import base64
import time
from asyncio.tasks import sleep

def rdtSend(currentSequence , currentAck , data):

    values = (currentACK, currentSequence, data)
    UDPData = struct.Struct('I I 8s')
    packedData = UDPData.pack(*values)
    checksumVal = hashlib.md5(packedData).hexdigest().encode('utf-8')
    sendPacket = makepacket(currentACK, currentSequence,  data, checksumVal)
    UDPSend(sendPacket)

def makepacket(currentACK, currentSequence, data, checksumVal):

    values = (currentACK, currentSequence, data, checksumVal)
    packetData = struct.Struct('I I 8s 32s')
    packet = packetData.pack(*values)
    return packet


def UDPSend(sendPacket):
        senderSocket.sendto(sendPacket, (IP, Port))


def dataError(receivePacket):

    checksum = makeChecksum(receivePacket[0], receivePacket[1], receivePacket[2])
    # Compare calculated chechsum with checksum value in packet
    if receivePacket[3] == checksum:
        print('CheckSums is OK')
        return False
    else:
        print('CheckSums Do Not Match')
        return True

def makeChecksum(ACK, SEQ, DATA):
    values = (ACK, SEQ, DATA)
    packer = struct.Struct('I I 8s')
    packedData = packer.pack(*values)
    checksum = hashlib.md5(packedData).hexdigest().encode('utf-8')
    return checksum

def isACK(receivePacket, ACKVal):
    
    if (receivePacket[0] == ACKVal):
        return True
    else:
        return False

IP = "127.0.0.1"
#Local Port for client and server
Port = 20001
#buffer to receive information from client
bufferSize  = 1024

unpacker = struct.Struct('I I 8s 32s')

senderSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
senderSocket.connect((IP , Port))

print("UDP IP:", IP)
print("UDP port:", Port)

filename = 'Cat.bmp'
file = open(filename , 'rb')
# current data item being processed
data = file.read(bufferSize)

currentSequence = 0
currentACK = 0

while (data):


    rdtSend(currentSequence, currentACK , data)
    
    packet, addr = senderSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    print(packet)

    print("Received from: ", addr) 
    receivePacket = unpacker.unpack(packet)

    if(dataError(receivePacket) == False and isACK(receivePacket ,  currentACK) == True):
        currentACK = currentACK + 1
        currentSequence  = (currentSequence + 1) % 2
        data = file.read(bufferSize)
        print("sending more data")
    else:
        print("Resending packet")


file.close()
senderSocket.close
```

**Server.py**

````
import socket
import binascii
import struct
import sys
import hashlib
import base64
import time
from asyncio.tasks import sleep

def rdtSend(currentSequence , currentAck , data):

    values = (currentACK, currentSequence, data)
    UDPData = struct.Struct('I I 8s')
    packedData = UDPData.pack(*values)
    checksumVal = hashlib.md5(packedData).hexdigest().encode('utf-8')
    #This is where it gets the UDP packet
    sendPacket = makepacket(currentACK, currentSequence,  data, checksumVal)
    UDPSend(sendPacket)

def makepacket(currentACK, currentSequence, data, checksumVal):

    values = (currentACK, currentSequence, data, checksumVal)
    packetData = struct.Struct('I I 8s 32s')
    packet = packetData.pack(*values)
    return packet

def UDPSend(sendPacket):
        receiverSocket.sendto(sendPacket, (IP, Port))

def makeChecksum(ACK, SEQ, DATA):
    values = (ACK, SEQ, DATA)
    packer = struct.Struct('I I 8s')
    packedData = packer.pack(*values)
    checksum = hashlib.md5(packedData).hexdigest().encode('utf-8')
    return checksum

#Function that checks the packet for corruption
def dataError(receivePacket):
    # Calculate new checksum of the  [ ACK, SEQ, DATA ]
    checksum = makeChecksum(receivePacket[0], receivePacket[1], receivePacket[2])
    # Compare calculated chechsum with checksum value in packet
    if receivePacket[3] == checksum:
        print('CheckSums is OK')
        return False
    else:
        print('CheckSums Do Not Match')
        return True

#IP Address for local communications
IP = "127.0.0.1"
#Local Port for client and server
Port = 20001
#buffer to receive information from client
bufferSize  = 1024

# Integer, Integer, 8 letter char array, 32 letter char array
unpacker = struct.Struct('I I 8s 32s')

# Create the actual UDP socket for the server
receiverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
# Bind the socket to the local IP address and port 
receiverSocket.bind((IP, Port))

currentACK = 0
currentSequence = 0
dataFile = open('receive.bmp' , 'wb')
print("Listening")
packet, addr = receiverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize) 
receivedPacket = unpacker.unpack(packet)

#Where the previous functions are used to send the packets back to the client
while receivedPacket[2]:
    print("Received from:", addr)
    print("Data Received:" , receivedPacket[2])

     #This compares checksums to see if there are errors
    if not dataError(receivedPacket):
        dataFile.write(receivedPacket[2])

        # Built checksum [ACK, SEQ, DATA]
        ACK = receivedPacket[0]
        SEQ = receivedPacket[1]
        DATA = b''
        print('Packeting')
        rdtSend(currentSequence , currentACK , DATA)
        print('Sent')
        currentACK = currentACK + 1
        currentSequence = (currentSequence + 1) % 2
        packet, addr = receiverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
        receivedPacket = unpacker.unpack(packet)
        

    else:
        print('Packet error')
        checksumVal = makeChecksum(packet[0] + 1, (packet[1] + 1) % 2, b'')
        packet = makepacket(packet[0] + 1, (packet[1] + 1) % 2, b'', checksumVal)
        print('Packeting')
        receiverSocket.sendto(packet, addr)
        print('Sent')
        packet, addr = receiverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize) 
        receivedPacket = unpacker.unpack(packet)

dataFile.close()
receiverSocket.close```
````

Comment: There are no lines in a BMP file, and there is no line-reading here.

Comment: @user207421 i have the lines where the file is opened and where the file is read, is that not enough?

Comment: You have lines of code. You don't have lines of BMP. It is binary data, and that's how you're reading it.

Comment: That's a hell of a lot of trouble.  Although UDP sockets are not literally guaranteed delivery, in practice they are reliable.  Is there a reason you're not using TCP, where you don't need the elaborate retry stuff?

Comment: Is the server actually signalling for retries?  Why?  Have you checked the data on both ends to see what doesn't match?

Comment: "Although UDP sockets are not literally guaranteed delivery, in practice they are reliable."  -- I assure you they are not :/

Comment: @TimRoberts, unfortunately, it is for a class I am taking so I must use UDP